# Re-enable a notification VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio

Let's get straight to the point here. So, every time I change a file name in Java, there was a notification in VS Code that said the code had been changed, like changing `public class HW` to `public class HelloWorld`. Once, I clicked Do Not Ask Me Again, and it stopped showing. I thought the notification was annoying, and stopped it, but since then I realized that it was a convenience. I know someone asked a similar question to this, but it didn't get any answers.